# Pegar link postado no Facebook

Tags: facebook

Alguém sabe como é possível pegar o link que foi postado no Facebook via *callback*?

Quero saber qual o link que foi gerado quando o usuário efetuou o compartilhamento, assim posso validar e até olhar se ele realmente fez um compartilhamento.

Tendo esta informação posso gravar ele no banco, inclusive para auditorias.

Não achei esta inoformação na documentação do Facebook até o momento

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10673018/753531) no SOEN, e também assumindo que esteja usando a API do Facebook, você pode processar os valores da entrada **links** retornados pelo OpenGraph, acessível a partir de:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/userID/links?access_token=<access_token>
```

Sendo *<access_token>* sua chave de autorização de uso.

Itere pelos links retornados (ao que parece, uma coleção de informações) e analise o valor da entrada **link** (no singular).

Uma consideração feita pelo autor da resposta original é que mesmo se definido um limite alto para o número de resultados, ainda assim é possível ter de lidar com paginações.